# Node.js module getter displaying undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a settings class that currently has one getter, and it looks like this:

```
class Settings {
    get domain() { return 'http://example.com'; }
}
module.exports.Settings = Settings;
```

In another file, I attempt to load it and display the value of the getter like this:

```
const Settings = require('./Settings');
console.log(Settings.domain);
```

When I run the app, my `console.log()` prints `undefined`. I am not sure why it is doing this. Am I forgetting to do something?

Comment: You need to use class instance, not the class itself. domain property will appear in instance of Settings class: `new Settings`.

Comment: Side note: should be `const Settings = require('./Settings').Settings;`, unless you change the export to `module.exports = Settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

```
class Settings {
    get domain() { return 'haslfjdasdf' }
}

const set = new Settings();

console.log(set.domain);
```

Or in your case:

```
const Settings = require('./test').Settings;
const set = new Settings();

console.log(set.domain);
```

Comment: it looks like I have to also make `get domain` into `static get domain`

Answer (score 1):

When you define a class like that, all the properties listed in the `class` block are attached to the class's **prototype**. `Settings` itself is actually a function; you can think of it as a constructor.

The `domain` getter, being on the prototype, will be available on *instances* of `Settings`, but it is not attached to the function object `Settings` itself.

You can access it in two ways:

```
// create an instance of Settings
var settings = new Settings();
console.log(settings.domain);   // => 'http://example.com'

// access Settings' prototype directly
console.log(Settings.prototype.domain);   // => 'http://example.com'
```

It is also possible to define the `domain` getter as `static`, which will signify that it should be available on the class function itself rather than its prototype:

```
// static getter
class Settings {
    static get domain() { return 'http://example.com'; }
}

console.log(Settings.domain);   // => 'http://example.com'
```